# How to train neural net to output a 2D polygon?

Tags: neural-networks, object-detection, geometry

Lets consider a net, that should map image to an arbitrary four-sided 2D polygon (all vertices are scaled to (0,0) - (1,1)). We need a loss function with a gradient to train it. If we try to use some simple loss function like euclidean distance between 4 target corners and 4 predicted corners - a problem arises. Target corners we supply to the net *aren't ordered*. Sure, we can list them in, say, clockwise order, but the start point will be random. Our loss function should expect (p1 p2 p3 p4) to be equal to (p2 p3 p4 p1). Any attempt, I think, to somehow fix the starting point (say, lets start with a point with min x, then clockwise) will result in instability in some cases (two points with equal minimal x) and the training will fail.

My first idea was to craft target data looking on a net output, selecting one of the four sequences ((p1 p2 p3 p4), (p2 p3 p4 p1), etc.) which gives minimal loss as target. Gradient descent thus will pursue closest sequence and converge on it. But in practice that failed due to stationary points - sometimes it gets stuck on *centers of polygon sides*, some training examples will push our 4 points clockwise, some - counterclockwise.

Maybe there is a better space for polygon data where euclidean distance loss can be used? Or maybe some custom loss function like Jaccard measure of polygon areas in some space will work and will not be prone to local minima or stationary points?

Going further: what if we want to train a neural net to output *totally unordered* data, like a set of N points? If this is 1D points we can presumably sort them, but what to do in 2D or higher dimensional case?

Comment: just to verify, are you trying to predict what kind of polygon the image is?

Comment: neural net should predict a bounding four-side polygon of an object of interest in an image (lets say object can be arbitraly rotated rectanglular or trapezoid-shaped) 

Tries to find colored rectangles exact positions in 32x32 image patches here:
http://take.ms/9Tcp9